# Map marker point and location doesn't showing on marshmallow

Tags: android, google-maps, location

In my map application it doesn't  showing location on marshmallows but its completely working on below marshmallows showing location and all marker point.

```
  context = MapsActivity.this;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap = googleMap;


    //drawing marker
    pointOne = new LatLng(23.10, 72.50847684);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pointOne).title("Point 1"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission IS required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return;
    }
```

Here i given all runtime permission m not able to see my curent location.
thanks for a help in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm that the if-statement that checks for permission and returns if not granted is not causing this. Add a debug statement there and confirm that it does not get printed (because if it does, then it means the permissions are not effected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its permission problem for marshmallow version brother.

1. first you have to turn on location of your device.
2. copy this code and paste into your activity class into onCreate() method.

   ```
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
           LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
   ```

hope this will works.

Comment: LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE??? what is for that and how to implement

Comment: in which activity you are using map, you have to write this after map.getMap() method for grant permission for android marshmallow.